# How to make a feature from str date for ML algorithms

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using a dataset where there is a date column full of str variables (format 'd/m/yy' ) and I have to use this column as a feature ( numeric variable ) for my ML algorithms. Unfortunatelly the `f.fit_transform` function didn't solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated
[Here's the Dataframe's head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXM9T.png)

Comment: Include an example of your dataframe so we understand what we are looking at. 5 - 10 rows is enough

Comment: I edited the post you can find it here :) I just want to convert the column date from str to date type

Comment: If your dataframes name is `df` use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: The date type can't be useful as feature to my ML algorithm I need a numeric type to be used :(

Answer (score 1):

Make three columns for date variables one for day 2nd for month and 3rd for year.